# MFC Serial Port WriteFile() Crash

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, serial-port

I am trying to write to a serial port using the WriteFile() function and when I put some breakpoints to check whether it is writing or not, it doesn't. I am trying to pass a string of data through my COMM port.

```
BOOL bWriteRC = false;
DWORD iBytesWritten = 0;

//String data: "$ABCEFG,00000020,010000003F800000*##\r\n" ==> stored in a CString

CString sStore = "$ABCEFG,00000020,010000003F800000*##\r\n";

bWriteRC = WriteFile(hdl,sStore.GetBuffer(),sStore.GetLength(),&iBytesWritten,NULL); // doesn't go past this...
```

Somehow whenever I execute it, the program doesn't go past this function and it stops. Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

I tried reducing the GetLength(), made it 14 and it works flawlessly but as soon as the number of bytes to write increases beyond 14, WriteFile() stops to go further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some surrounding code?  Any information from the debugger?  What sort of crash is it?

Comment: As in it doesn't "Crash" crash. It just doesn't go past the WriteFile() function. Surrounding code added as edit.

Comment: What part of code were you interested in? The handle and everything else in terms of setting the comport is fine. It initializes well.

Comment: Serial port WriteFile should always succeed assuming that file handle is OK. First of all, disconnect any device from COM port and execute this line - does it work? If device works incorrectly, WriteFile may hang, bit without device it should work.

Comment: Change your CString to a CStringA and see if that works ...

Comment: @ Alex and Goz: tried, no luck. It has something to do with the string length. I have edited my question.

Comment: Two side notes: 1. `CString::GetBuffer()`, gets you a mutable buffer, which you can change directly. After you call it, you should call `ReleaseBuffer`. In your case, casting to `LPCTSTR` would be enough. 2. `WriteFile` expects an array of bytes, and its size in bytes - not its number of characters. To get that, you can multiply the length of the CString with the `sizeof(TCHAR)` or so. Otherwise, you'll be writing only half of the string in Unicode builds.

Comment: @ Eran: thanks for your inputs. I have tried both the techniques and unfortunately both of them do not seem to work for some unknown reason.

Comment: Should this operation be considered as Overlapped by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your question, WriteFile() should always succeed as Alex mentioned earlier. Better check the string which you are trying to write is correct or not and is acceptable on the serial port or not. Sometimes, such small things might be overseen and result in big errors. Other than that, in my opinion it should work if it is a simple write operation.

Answer (score 0):

If it hangs in WriteFile it means that COM port driver does not accept your data, it cannot send it to COM port. It depends on such COM port setting as DTR signal state. You need to check flow control settings.

Comment: WriteFile worked before and accepted the data earlier every single time I tried to write. So, I am 100% sure there is no problem with my COM port settings.

Comment: If WriteFile crashes then you have problem with WriteFile parameters. If it returns error then you have problems with the parameters or with port handle. But if it just hangs forever then you have problem with COM port flow control.

Comment: I am guessing there is something wrong with the string length. I have edited my question.

Comment: I still think it is flow control problem, try to call WriteFile twice with 14 chars, second call must hang. If it is related to string somehow then you can trace data sent to COM port with PORTMON from SysInternals.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It does not hang and both the write functions get executed.

Comment: Does PortMon show that data sent to COM port? Did you get the data on remote side?

Comment: No the data is not transmitted because the WriteFile() function has 14 as the string length which is nowhere equal to the size required for the whole data transmission(38 number of characters as per the above given string) to get transmitted.

Comment: If you specify 14 then WriteFile must send 14 bytes, why do you think that WriteFile will transmit data only if you specify 38 bytes? Even if you send one byte it must be transmitted. And it's a good idea to check what data is sent to COM port via PortMon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3696/discussion-between-nerds-dont-swear-and-michael)